# How do I arrive at the total individual expenses I had during a trip with my friend?

Tags: travel-tools

I went with my friend to Europe. We tracked all our common expenses on Splitwise app.

We tracked all these -
- the expense before the journey - including accommodation and travel tickets.
- any money we gave each other before or during the trip.

I went with Rs. X in hand (cash plus card), sent him Rs. Y because his credit card had no balance to pay for our bookings, then lent him Rs. Z overall from my bank account.

Splitwise shows he owes me Rs. A as final settlement.
I was left with no money out of the original I had taken with me.

How much was my total expense?

Comment: This seems more like a math question than a travel question ... But what's missing is how much of X you personally had left when you got home.

Comment: Forgot to add, I was left with no money from the money I took with me.

Comment: Your cash in hand is irrelevant.  Assuming he is going to repay the two loans, your actual expenses are whatever Splitwise says they are.

Answer (score 3):

If you've tracked all your expenses in Splitwise, you can use its reporting tools for this.

Go to "All Expenses" and choose the trends button

[image]

Then click "view full charts"

You'll get a month-by-month breakdown of your expenses (be sure to check all months if your trip covered more than one) broken down by the total spending, what you paid for, your share, and your net balance. The sum of the "Your Share" column is your total expense.

[image]